# How to edit Expression Admin panel

Tags: ee2, control-panel, add-on-development, admin

I need to customize the Admin Control Panel in Expression Engine I don't know how to do it. If any one knows kindly tell me.

**Updated**
Actually I want to show the channel data(any entries) in different UI inside EE2 Admin panel and I have my own module and I need to show that modules records also in EE2 Admin panel.

Comment: Hi Ezhil, can you provide a little more information on what aspect you are hoping to customize? Is it the control panel navigation? The style (theme)?

Comment: Actually i want to show the channel data(any entries) in different UI inside EE2 Admin panel and i have my own module and  i need to show that modules records also in EE2 Admin panel.

Comment: Gotcha. I added your comment as an edit on the original question and posted an answer below on where to start on building a module control panel.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to change the column layout as well as the look, try the module Zenbu. It will let you customize which columns are visible from the Edit Entries view. You can show expiration dates, edit dates, custom field data, etc. You can also vary what columns are shown based on member groups.

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zenbu

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague. But there are a couple of things you can do.

For style changes EE-Garage's override.css would be a good starting point:

http://ee-garage.com/override-css

You can also create your own by making a folder inside '/themes/cp_themes/'
So you'd have '/themes/cp_themes/**yourcustomthemename**'
Inside this folder you make duplicates of the existing system files you want to make changes to.

So for example if you wanted to make changes to:
'/themes/cp_themes/default/css/login.css'

you would make your own version inside your custom theme folder:
'/themes/cp_themes/**yourcustomthemename**/css/login.css'

You can also change files within the '/system/expressionengine/views/' folder.
for example if you wanted to change:
'/system/expressionengine/views/_shared/footer.php' (the control panel footer)

you can make a folder in your own theme folder:
'/themes/cp_themes/**yourcustomthemename**/_shared/footer.php'

You only need to make copies of the files you wish to change as expressionengine 
will 'fall back' to the default where it can't find the file in your custom theme.

Finally, most importantly, to get this to work you need to set your custom theme in the control panel:
Log in to the CP > Admin > General Configuration > Default Control Panel Theme > choose your theme from the dropdown box

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned in your comment...

> I have my own module and I need to show that modules records also in
>   EE2 Admin panel.

In that case, what you need to do is use a module ["Control Panel File"](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/modules.html#the-control-panel-file-mcp-module-name-php) `mcp.module_name.php` in your module. This file in conjunction with some [view files](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/modules.html#view-files), will give you a way to present your module data in the Control Panel.

The [module tutorial](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/module_tutorial.html) in the documentation gives an example of how to put it together.

> I want to show the channel data(any entries) in different UI inside
>   EE2

You could add methods in your mcp file to display Channel data, too.

A really quick and easy way to generate the necessary files and boilerplate for a module or other ExpressionEngine add-on is to use this [ExpressionEngine Add-On generator](https://github.com/rsanchez/generator-ee-addon) for Yeoman.

Answer (score 0):

[dashEE](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dashee) is another great plug in that allows you to alter the main dashboard and replace it with a lot of useful tools.